# Ignore @JsonValue annotation without subclassing

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Let's suppose there is a class hierarchy in some third-party library. One of those classes has `@JsonValue` annotation. It results in serialization/deserialization of only one field. Is it possible to ignore `@JsonValue` annotation without subclassing and get all object fields serialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a MixIn and override the `@JsonValue` via property or getter 
 - depending on where the annotation has been set in the third-party library.

Assuming we have a class `Pojo` with a `@JsonValue` annotated member `prop`:

```
class Pojo {
    @JsonValue
    private String prop;
    private String prop2;
    // getters and setters
}
```

We then define an abstract `MixIn` class like follows, overriding the particular member or method:

```
abstract class MixIn {
    @JsonValue(false) // either annotating members
    private String prop;

    @JsonValue(false) // or annotating methods
    abstract String getProp();
}
```

This can be added to the `ObjectMapper` like follows:

```
objectMapper.addMixIn(Pojo.class, MixIn.class);
```

Instead of just `prop`, now both `prop` and `prop2` are serialized.